# Send a PowerPoint presentation as read-write

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint, read-write

I'm working on a group project on PowerPoint, I'm doing the research and my friend is doing the animation and design. When I sent it to him, it seems like it's set to only read. He doesn't have a Microsoft account so I can't share it via OneDrive.

How can he open and edit it ?

PS. I tried sending him the file on email and on Discord but still the same result

Comment: Office opens emailed documents in "read mode" by default for security purposes,  it should be as easy as clicking the button that says "enable editing".

Answer (score 2):

He shouldn't need a MS or OneDrive account to open the file if you use OneDrive to create a link (making sure it's set to allowing anyone with the link to edit the file).  If you use the email a link feature from OneDrive (or dropbox) the email recipient needs to log in.

Rightclick the file, choose Share then in the dialog box that appears, click Copy Link. The dialog box changes, copy the link shown, then paste it into an email to your co-worker.

Have him download the file, right-click it, choose Properties, then choose to unblock the file.

Send a Thank You card to MS for making your lives so secure.  Or at least giving you the opportunity to practice The Dance of Many Hoops.